# Mongo error: "unknown top level operator: $completed_on" for aggregate

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to perform aggregate operation with Mongo which is like follows:

```
db.inbound_documents.aggregate([{"$match": 
{"$completed_on": 
{"$gte":'2018-05-19 00:00:00',
"$lte":'2017-05-19 00:00:00'}}},
{"$group":
{"_id":"$completed_by","total":{"$sum":1}}}])
```

completed_on is available in the schema, Still I am not getting that why it is causing that error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just remove your $ sign before completed_on :

```
db.inbound_documents.aggregate([
{"$match": 
  {"completed_on": 
    {"$gte":'2018-05-19 00:00:00',
    "$lte":'2017-05-19 00:00:00'}}},
  {"$group":
    {"_id":"$completed_by","total":{"$sum":1}}}])
```